# Sending TCP Packets through IP Address

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, tcp

I know you can send UDP, HTTP, and TCP packets in java to a specific IP address. Since i'm learning c# i decided to make a Low Orbit Ion Cannon. Basically its used for stress testing network. So i'm kinda curious is their anyway to send TCP packets in c#. Could you give me some code examples? I tried to look online but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Did you search for "[C# Sockets](https://www.google.com/#q=c%23+sockets)" or "[c# tcp/ip](https://www.google.com/#q=c%23+tcp%2Fip)"?

Comment: Yea i did but i just got junk

Answer (score 1):

I would have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket(v=vs.110).aspx for an introduction of what C# can do for you using a socket. And http://www.csharp-examples.net/socket-send-receive/ has an example of send and receive using a socket.

Comment: Thank you for the help! It's greatly appreciated!